# best way to hide loading html and css when page load?

Tags: javascript, load

My webpage has got a fade in UI effect when first load(header, footer and divs fade in slowly after loading).

The problem is that when when the page loads, there will be a split second or two, depends on the internet connection that the HTML and css being loaded(but not the javascript controlling the fade in effect). Is there any good practice to avoid viewer from seeing the loading part?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just HIDE the html completely, set the CSS of the container element to have a style of

```
display: none;
```

Since you have a fade effect, it'll display it for you as it performs the fade in.